# Recursively collect all checked QTreeview items in python

Tags: python, qt, search, pyside, qtreeview

Could someone help me create a recursive function which loops through the treeview QStandardItemModel and collects all items which are 'checked true'

I'm not entirely clear on how to go about doing this myself.

[image]

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from PySide import QtSvg, QtXml
import sys

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name="", children=None):
        self.name = name
        self.children = children if children else []

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 400)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # Setup Tabs Widget
        # self.treeview = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.treeview = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.treeview.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.treeview.setUniformRowHeights(True)
        self.treeview.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.treeview.setModel(self.model)

        self.action = QtGui.QAction('Print', self)
        self.action.setShortcut('F5')
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.get_checked)

        fileMenu = QtGui.QMenu("&File", self)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menuBar().addMenu(fileMenu)

        # Setup central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.treeview)

        # populate data
        self.populate_people()
        self.treeview.expandAll()

    def populate_people(self):
        parent = Person("Kevin", [
                Person("Tom", [Person("Sally"), Person("Susan")]),
                Person("Snappy", [Person("John"), Person("Kimmy"),
                                  Person("Joe")]),
                Person("Chester", [Person("Danny"), Person("Colleen")])
            ]
        )
        self.create_nodes(parent, self.model)

    def create_nodes(self, node, parent):
        tnode = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        tnode.setCheckable(True)
        tnode.setData(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked, role=QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
        tnode.setData(node.name , role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        tnode.setData(node, role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole) # store object on item

        parent.appendRow(tnode)

        for x in node.children:
            self.create_nodes(x, tnode)

    def get_checked(self):
        print "collecting..."


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with the model's [match](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#match) method:

```
def get_checked(self):
    model = self.treeview.model()
    checked = model.match(
        model.index(0, 0), QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole,
        QtCore.Qt.Checked, -1,
        QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly | QtCore.Qt.MatchRecursive)
    for index in checked:
        item = model.itemFromIndex(index)
        print(item.text())
```

Comment: Is there a way to collect which items are expanded?

Comment: @JokerMartini. `self.treeview.isExpanded(index)`.